# MonoTouch binding: How to mark framework library as optionally-linked?

Tags: binding, ios6, linker, xamarin.ios

I am trying to build a binding project that should optionally link ios 6.0 framework libraries (AdSupport, Social, Accounts).

Is there any way to mark those libraries as optionally-linked in `LinkWithAttribute` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the `WeakFrameworks`, instead of the `Frameworks`, in your `[LinkWith]` attribute. E.g.

```
[LinkWith (..., Frameworks="Foundation", WeakFrameworks="AdSupport, Social, Accounts")]
```

Comment: for some reason adding `Frameworks="AVFoundation"` causes my main project to not find the binding project's namespace...